# MATLAB convolution in inf interval

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How I can calculate the convolution `Y3 = Y1*Y2` and plot it? Same for `Y4 = Y3*Y3` using interval `t ∈ [0, inf)` with `subplot`, `conv` and `title`.

I have done `Y1` and `Y2`:

```
clear all
y1=@(t)(exp(-0.5*t));
t=linspace(0,10);
i = 10;t(i) = [];
figure(1)
plot(t,y1(t))
grid
figure(2)
y2=@(n)(sin(3*n));
n=linspace(0,10);
n(i) = []; 
plot(n,y2(n))
grid
y3 = @(p)(conv(y1,y2));
```